# Data reader incompatiable error when Entity Framework model generated from a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

After adding a new stored procedure to my database, and updating my Entity Frameowork model in Visual Studio 2012 I receive the following error message:

**The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyDb.usp_GetRolesForUser_Result'. A     member of the type, 'RoleType', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.**

I don't understand how this problem can be happening as the model was generated from the database/stored procedure. I have tried removing the stored procedure from the model (stored procedures, function imports, and complex types folders) then refreshing form the database.

Note: This is used by a class library and I am receiving the error when I use an MVC web app to test the class library. I have made sure I have rebuilt both projects.

If I remove *r.RoleType,* from the select statement, refresh the model and rebuild the projects then there is no error. RoleType is an nvarchar(100), AppName is an nvarchar(250).

Stored procedure:

```
USE [MyDb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRolesForUser]
    @i_intId int = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY

SELECT r.RoleId, r.RoleType, a.AppId, a.AppName
    FROM [USER] u INNER JOIN [USERROLE] ur on u.UserId = ur.FkUserId            
        INNER JOIN [ROLE] r on ur.FkRoleId = r.RoleId
        INNER JOIN [APPLICATION] a on r.FkAppId = a.AppId
    WHERE u.UserId = @i_intId
    ORDER BY a.AppName, r.RoleType

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   /*error catching*/
END CATCH

RETURN
```

Generated class:

```
public partial class usp_GetRolesForUser_Result
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleType { get; set; }
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a simple solution in the end, as is usual with the problems you spend hours trying to diagnose!

I had changed the database that the class library was connecting to recently, but the testbed web app's connection string had not been updated.

So I was sitting there, with a colleague, looking at the code and both of us were saying there was nothing wrong, and it turns out we were right; the incorrect code was in the web app's web.config.